# Diseño para móvil

Tags: css, bootstrap

El problema esta en que tengo estos dos botones y quiero que cuando sea para dispositivos pequeños queden un poco separados entre ellos.

Así es como me quedan ahora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Codigo que tengo.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="guardarCambios" value="Guardar Cambios" onclick="return validarPersona()">Guardar Cambios</button>
                  <button type="button" id="borrarUsuario" class="btn btn-secondary">Borrar Usuario</button>
                </div>
              </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo agregale un Stylo al boton con el id="guardarCambios" de esta maneta yo lo haria.

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="guardarCambios" value="Guardar Cambios" onclick="return validarPersona()" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Guardar Cambios</button>
              <button type="button" id="borrarUsuario" class="btn btn-secondary">Borrar Usuario</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

O se lo agregas al archivo .css ejemplo:

```
#guardarCambios { margin-bottom: 5px; }
```